# CSS alpha opacity IE8 overflow is being hidden

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter, opacity, alpha

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?  The inner class 'tab' is supposed to have a negative top margin but when the `-ms-filter:Alpha(opacity=40);` gets applied, the container seems to have a overflow:hidden forced.

Remember this is only happening in IE8.  Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ANh4k/2/

Please let me know if there is more information I can provide, and thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** this is a screenshot using IE8 developer tools, I've unchecked as many options as possible to try to figure out what is causing the opacity problem (keep in mind, `-ms-filter:...` does not show in the IE8 CSS developer list; but it is applied).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got rid of the z-index in the fiddle.. that z-index confuses IE8, and it believes that you don't want overflow when you have it.. That is IE for you...

http://jsfiddle.net/ANh4k/40/

```
  #feed-container-outline.mini.active {
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        zoom:1;
        right:5px;
        top:45px;
        width:370px;
        height:53%;
        min-height:320px;
        background:#ED9A27;
        opacity:.4;
        border:2px solid #F16719;
        -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #aaa;
        -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #aaa;
        -o-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #aaa;
        box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #aaa;
        overflow:visible;
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)"; 
}


 #feed-container-outline.mini.active .tab {
        display:block;
        overflow:auto;
        position:absolute;
        float:right;
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)";
        width:70px;
        right:-1px;
        top:-45px;
        height:45px;
        background:#ED9A27;
        border:2px solid #F16719;
        border-bottom: 0px;
}​
```

Comment: The problem I've got is that for some reason when I use the -ms-filter:"progid......" syntax, the opacity does not work (it is not even the slightest bit opac. Now when I use `filter:Alpha(opacity=40);` the opacity is applied and renders fine, but now the overflow hidden problem is still happening.... what can I do?

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but it renders fine for me in IE8 using the fiddle I made... Try lower case o in Opacity in that same fiddle I posted. And see that there is no z-index. That sorted the whole thing for me, so try your first fiddle without z-index too.. I'm not at a computer at the moment, so I can't check.. But I got it work just then.

Comment: Lower-case 'o' in opacity did not fix it for me.  Interestingly enough your fiddle does work fine for me in IE8, just my site is not displaying it properly which is odd because I replaced my previous element style with your exact syntax.  Any other ideas, perhaps someone else in my CSS that is conflicting with it? but what?

Comment: Interesting indeed... I cannot see why it shouldn't work! Now with no z-index, have you tried the filter:opacity rather than the progid....one? Also, on your site, is there a parent div that has a z-index to it that you might try to get rid of? Also, did you copy my code from here or fom my fiddle? Take the one in the fiddle that you know works.

Comment: I copied the one from the fiddle ;).  Also, I am using the opacity implementation syntax of `-ms-filter:"Alpha(opacity=40)";`. And the only two divs involved in this design are the two you already have worked on....I added a screenshot to my OP, check it out.

Comment: The strange thing is that it works in the fiddle still.. What does the selectable css chart on the left show when you have a filter element that actually applies opacity to the div? Even if it takes out overflow.. Because like u mentioned, it doesnt show that ms filter is loaded..

Comment: Try and add both `-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";` and 
`filter: alpha(opacity=50);` to both divs, in that order.